# FastICA and Blind Signal Separation Mathematics Question

Tags: math, vector, matrix, probability

I'm trying to make my own implementation of the FastICA algorithm based on the paper here: http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/papers/NN00new.pdf.

I need some help w/ the math though.

In the middle of page 14 there is an equation that looks somewhat like

w+ = E{ xg(w^Tx) } - E{ g[prime]( w^T x)} w

What does the E mean? Back from my probability days I recall that it is the "expected value" of a random variable but it doesn't make sense to me what the expected value of a vector is.

Thanks,

mj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ICA is interesting stuff. I used it some in my graduate research, but I didn't dig in too much under the hood; I just downloaded the FastICA implementation for MatLab and used that.

Anyway, you are correct that E{...} denotes expected value. The elements of the vector x represent the individual signals.  Strictly speaking, x is a time series and should be written x(t), but the convention in ICA is to treat x instead as a random variable.  In that context, of course, the idea of expected value makes sense.  For example E{x} would just be the mean value of x (taken to be zero in ICA as the signals have been centered).

The authors of the paper you linked also have [a book on ICA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047140540X). It's outrageously expensive on Amazon, but if you can find a copy at, say, a nearby university library, it might be worth a look.  It's been several years, but I remember it as being as gentle an introduction as one could hope for given the mathematics.

Comment: Thanks eaj. I'm looking to use FastICA on an audio stream of 3 motors running (3 microphones).
For line 2 of the paper, when looking at the E{xg(w^T w)} component,I presume that x is the entire matrix of measurements. I can do xg(w^T w) and I assume that the output of this is a vector. In order to get the expectation (expectation = P(measurement)*Value) I run through the data looking for sensor input that matches the vector and count how many times it shows up in order to get its probability and then multiply that prob by the vector itself to get the expectation.
Am I on the right track?

Comment: @mj_ You're getting a little beyond what I've done directly, but... x is the vector of observed values (3 elements in your case); s is the vector of original values; A is the (unknown constant) mixing matrix: x=As. The matrix W is the inverse of A, and the w vectors are its columns. You're probably on the right track estimating the expectation values--see the last paragraph of section 6.1 in the paper. However, unless your main goal is the coding (if it is, then more power to you!), I'd recommend using available software: http://research.ics.tkk.fi/ica/fastica/

Comment: I've been reading the code that you provided the link to. I think that it may have a problem that I can't run it on the platform that I want to because it uses several other packages that aren't present. It is pretty cool though.